# Creating an Interactive bar Chart out of Google Analytics Data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, charts, google-analytics

I want to make a bar chart from the google analytics data.
Current implemetation of the bar chart in my site is by [See Analytics](http://codecanyon.net/item/see-analytics/77476)

I am developing an ASP.NET website and this See Analytics is using PHP and jQuery to conjure the chart. It is also paid.
What my client would like is a similar tool that draws chart from analytics, without a PHP Component in it. ie. A similar tool using ASP.NET and jQuery/javascript.
What I would like is to get that tool for free(open source).

What are my options?

Regards,
naveenj

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the other free tools from Google:

The Google Visualization API: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/

The Google Chart API: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

They have some examples of how to use analytics data with the charts libraries.

Comment: i am looking for an implementaion combining both google analytics and googlecharts/ any other chart plugins/.net chart controls...

Comment: Here is an example using it though they do use PHP. But I imagine you could convert that php to asp.net with little trouble.

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/06/23/google-analytics-data-export-api-with-google-chart-visualizations-2/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is an excellent [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)-plugin for making such graphs and more importantly it's open source. I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, but there are [good examples available](http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/103-introducing-google-analytics-api-with-aspnet-c.html) for Google Analytics API connectivity in ASP.NET.

I would do it with PHP and jQuery + flot and it would probably be the easiest way too. Another option is to use [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) for the graphs, which is a similar JavaScript framework as jQuery. Even with MooTools the data should be retrieved with PHP.

Here's an example of [jQuery + flot + Google Analytics](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-flot) which is just what you are looking for even though it's implemented with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Google Analytics API](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/) Gallery.  There are a lot of solutions there.  I have created a 3rd party service ([www.embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com)) which does exactly this.  Mind you it is not a source code solution.  But rather a 3rd party SaaS.  And there are free options available.